# Alinhar menu com CSS

Tags: html, css

Possuo esse menu que no momento tem duas ID que podem ser mais.

```
  <ul>
  <li><span class="ytVideo" data-videoID="6AmRg3p79pM">(Youtube 1)</span></li>
  <li><span class="ytVideo" data-videoID="El3IZFGERbM">(Youtube 2) </span>       
</li>
```

Como podem ver existe duas ID do youtube nelas, gostaria de alinhar elas uma ao lado da outra. ao inves de uma abaixo da outra. é um menu clicavel.

css do menu

```
  #videoGallery ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 #videoGallery span {
display: block;
background-color: steelblue;
color: #fff;
font-family: sans-serif;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 4px 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  }

  #videoGallery li {
position: relative;
  }
 span.nowPlaying {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
 }
```

Exemplo de como deve ficar: https://jsfiddle.net/zh61vq0z/6/

Comment: Veja se esse exemplo lhe serve: https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/zh61vq0z/8/

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar um `display: inline-block` em seu `li`. De acordo com seu código funciona perfeitamente.

```css
#videoGallery ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#videoGallery span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4682b4;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#videoGallery li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
span.nowPlaying {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="videoGallery">

  <ul>
    <li><span class="ytVideo" data-videoID="El3IZFGERbM">(Youtube 1)</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="ytVideo" data-videoID="El3IZFGERbM">(Youtube 2)</span>
    </li>
    <li><span id="close">Fechar Tudo</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a propriedade `float:left`, que fará com que seus menus fiquem um ao lado do outro.
Para tirar esse efeito onde desejar pode usar o `clear: left;`

Este tutorial pode lhe ajudar:
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://www.richardbarros.com.br/blog/css/css-truques-para-dominar-a-propriedade-float)